# JWT based authentication with RESTful apis

Tags: c#, api, rest

I'm exploring authentication with JWT's and so I don't much but know much but do know enough on how to create one, what they are for and how they are used. I have a login api endpoint where users send an email and password and this will then validate the request and sign the user in if its a valid account. The login api sends back in the response:

```
public class SignInResult
{
   public bool Succeeded { get; set; }
   public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
   public bool IsNotAllowed { get; set; }
   public bool RequiresTwoFactor { get; set; }
}
```

This object is from .NET Identity. My question is, in a RESTful api world, would you expect to make a request to login, if that succeeds then make a request to get a token? Or would you expect to return the token in the response model?

I have 2 ideas, one of them is:

- Make a request to /login with an email and password
- If the `Succeeded` flag is set to `true` then make a request to /request/token

The other is to change the response model to just return a token, and for the different flags that were initially returned use HTTP Status codes, like so:

- Succeeded - Return `200` with the users token
- IsLockedOut - Return `401`
- IsNotAllowed - Return `403`
- RequiresTwoFactor - Not sure what to return here?

What is the best thing to do in this situation?

Comment: Normally when you call the login API, it returns a success `and` a JWT token that can be used in successive calls.

Comment: How would the different scenarios work if the frontend needs to know whether it requires 2FA, or if the account IsLockedOut or IsNotAllowed ? @Jawad

Comment: Sounds like you reinvent the wheel. There are existing authentication protocols already like OpenID connect. Just follow these.